# Can anyone help me figure out why I'm stuck in a loop? And can I write it simpler?

Tags: java

my goal is to take the first letter of a word and moving it to the end until the first letter is a vowel. this is pig latin

```
    System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
    String word = keyboard.nextLine();
    String y = word.substring(0,1);
    String z = word.substring(1);

    char x = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0));

    if ((x=='a') || (x=='e') || (x=='i') || (x=='o') || (x=='u')) {
        System.out.println(word + "ay ");
    } 

    while ((x!='a') || (x!='e') || (x!='i') || (x!='o') || (x!='u')) {
        String s = z+y;
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that in your `while` loop, you never update the value of `x`. Therefore the program never terminates. In an effort to make your "pig latin" more readable and easier to debug, you should consider breaking your program into **methods**.

Such as:

```
public static boolean isVowel(char input){
    input = Character.toLowerCase(input);
    return ((input=='a') || (input=='e') || (input=='i') || (input=='o') || (input=='u'));
}
```

So that then you would be able to do:

```
System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
String word = keyboard.nextLine();

while (!isVowel(word.charAt(0))){ //while the first character isn't a vowel do this:
    word = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0);
}

System.out.println(word);
```

However beware that if there is no vowel this program will still run into a infinite loop.

Without methods the code would look something like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
String word = keyboard.nextLine();

char currentChar = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0));
while (!((currentChar=='a') || (currentChar=='e') || (currentChar=='i') || (currentChar=='o') || (currentChar=='u'))){ //while the first character isn't a vowel do this:
    word = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0);
    currentChar = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0));
}

System.out.println(word);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes it helps a little. But I'm still not too confident using methods for now. How would the whole entire code look?

Comment: @duBz180 I added a block of code which should work without the use of a method.

Answer (score 0):

You keep doing checks on the variable `x`, but you are not updating its value in the loop body. Therefore, the condition keeps being verified.
In other words

1. First iteration: Is x different from a vowel?
2. If so, build the s string and print it
3. Second iteration: Is x different from a vowel?
4. Same as 2... and so on.